# Embed UIPageViewController inside UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to embed a UIPageViewController inside of my UIView. InfoViewController is being presented modally and over current context. I am not sure if it can be done the way I am trying to achieve, but I want the UIPageView to be the same size as my container view with everything behind the container view to be transparent.

```
 class HomeScreen: UIViewController{
        func showSInfo() {

    let modalViewController = InfoViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
   }

    class InfoViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
var pages = [UIViewController]()

let containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    return view
}()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    let initialPage = 0
    let page1 = InformationPageOne()
    let page2 = InformationPageTwo()
    let page3 = InformationPageThree()

    // add the individual viewControllers to the pageViewController
    self.pages.append(page1)
    self.pages.append(page2)
    self.pages.append(page3)
    setViewControllers([pages[initialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
     view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 130, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 200, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
   }
```

Comment: Where do you have your container view? From the above code, it seems like you have added that to the InfoViewController's view only. If so, where do you want to embed the controller into? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The size of the container view is set by my constraints, containerView.anchor. I don't know if that will make a big difference. I want the controller to be the same exact size as the container view

Comment: You're adding the containerView you have in your code into the UIPageViewController. So you can't expect to embed the UIPageViewController in the same view. Rather, you can have a view controller add container view into it with your desired constraints and add the UIPageViewController into it. Hope it helps.